# Highlighting with php generated checkbox form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this page setup where I can highlight the selected values with checkbox on the table. And this code works fine. 
https://jsfiddle.net/zt54jqtL/

When I try to replace the static form1 code with the following php generated code, it doesn't highlight the selected cells. How can I fix this problem? please. Thank you!

The php code that I implement is this:

```
<?php 

include 'etc/config.php';

mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

$subjectName = 'SELECT * FROM tablea order by Week DESC';
$subject = mysqli_query($conn, $subjectName);
?>

  <div>
 <form method="post" action=" ">

<?php 

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($subject)) {
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox'  class='selector' value='{$data['Value1']}'>" . $data['Value1'];
    echo "<input type='checkbox'  class='selector' value='{$data['Value2']}'>" . $data['Value2'];
    echo "<input type='checkbox'  class='selector' value='{$data['Value3']}'>" . $data['Value3'];
    echo "<input type='checkbox'  class='SelectAll'>All";
     echo "</div>";
}
?>


 </form>
   <script>

    $(".SelectAll").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I think your problem is related to dynamic content event binding please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).

Comment: @vikscool dynamic content binding shouldn't be a problem since the items are added on the server side and not client side

Comment: Working fine on mine. Did you check your browser console as if there is any javascript errors or did you forgot to load jquery

Comment: What works fine exactly with your browser? It works when I click an individual value, but not with select all.

Comment: It is woking even I clicked on Select all

Comment: hmm. that's strange. I tried this on chrome, firefox, and opera. It didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you check your console if there is any errors

Comment: Thanks, Suraj. yes, it all works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP, you are generating checkboxes with their **value** attribute set to the number you're looking for.

However, if you're using the same JS found in the fiddle, it is looking for the **name** of the checkbox instead:

```
var checked = $(".selector:checked").map(function() {
  return this.name
}).get()
```

You need to change your JS to grab the value instead like this:

```
var checked = $(".selector:checked").map(function() {
  return this.value
}).get()
```

Additionally, your script at the end of the PHP file doesn't trigger the click even on the other checkboxes, therefore the highlighting function doesn't fire. Try this instead:

```
<script>
    $(".SelectAll").click(function () {
      if (this.checked) 
          $(this).parent().find('.selector:not(:checked)').click();
      else
          $(this).parent().find('.selector:checked').click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, your solution is partially right. when I click the individual values, it highlights on the table. but it doesn't highlight when I click "all".

Comment: yes, it works altogether now. thanks a lot, @user45940